Upgrading to Spring Boot 3 causing annotation processing errors
I am in the process of upgrading our existing application from Spring Boot 2.7.8 to 3.0.13. The core Spring Boot library is being pulled in through a custom common library our team uses. I'm using IntelliJ 2022.1.2 Ultimate Edition (for Mac), JDK 17, and Lombok. When compiling my POM, I get multiple errors similar to this:

    <file location>:[85,69] error: cannot find symbol
        symbol:   method getRuleName()
        location: class RuleManagerDto


...and this:

    <file location>:[9,64] error: cannot find symbol
        symbol:   class ResultBuilder
        location: class Result


The errors start after this line in the compiling process: maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile)...
I'm assuming the issue is related to annotation processing, specifically the @Data and @Builder annotations. I've tried the following things to address the issue:

added the following code under the maven-compiler-plugin element:


    <annotationProcessorPaths>
        <path>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.24</version>
        </path>
        <path>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.0</version>
        </path>
        <path>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok-mapstruct-binding</artifactId>
            <version>0.2.0</version>
        </path>
    </annotationProcessorPaths>



used <annotationProcessorPath> in place of <path> above
updated Lombok dependency to v1.18.24 ans v1.18.36
updated Maven compiler plugin to v3.8.1
added <optional> property to Lombok dependency
added <forceJavacCompilerUse>true</forceJavacCompilerUse>
changed all Lombok imports to use "*" vs. actual class names
added <scope>provided</scope> to Lombok dependency

None of these potential remedies have fixed the problem. I am invalidating the cache and restarting after every attempted fix. I am also using the update switch when compiling: mvn clean -U install. My colleague has suggested that the problem is with a related library that is out of date, which is plausible. However, I'm not getting any errors other than the types listed above, so I have no idea which library it could be.

This is most likely a compilation problem not directly related to Lombok. javac won't call Lombok when certain errors occur. Also check for non-star static imports for Lombok-annotated classes, and replace them with star (*) imports. Furthermore, update to the latest Lombok version.

Thanks Jan - I'll try these suggestions.

Please show the full pom file....Why using an old Spring Boot version? Not the most recent version? Why using an old IntelliJ version?

I'm using an older Spring Boot version because I work for a corporation. People way above my pay-grade make those decisions. I'm using an older version of IntelliJ for pretty much the same reason.

The annotation processing errors have been eliminated. In the POM, I changed <springdoc.version>1.6.0</springdoc.version> to <springdoc.version>1.8.0</springdoc.version>. One of my coworkers found this fix. I'm not sure where he came up with it, so I can't point to a source. I'm receiving many new errors, but at least these ones are fixed. Thanks to everyone who responded.

These methods or classes that's causing these errors might have either changed or been removed when upgrading Spring Boot.
If you haven't done any of the following, try doing these:

Remove the import statements where the class/method is failing (e.g. getRuleName(), ResultBuilder). Depending on your IDE, the class name that's not being picked up will be picked up from another path.
Check your libraries in the pom.xml file and make sure they're compatible for the Spring Boot upgrade. Maybe check if ResultBuilder or RuleManagerDto is coming from a library in your pom.xml. If it has a library, see if upgrading it to a version compatible to Spring Boot 3+ will resolve it.
I think this was mentioned already, but check if lombok has a compatible version for the Spring Boot upgrade.

Hope this advice helps!
P.S.This is my first StackOverFlow contribution :)

All of the classes referenced in the errors are part of our application - they aren't imported 3rd-party libraries. I'm trying to update them now. The "get" method names and "Builder" classes are generated by Lombok, so they wouldn't be part of the imports. I have been going through the POM, but it's almost 800 lines long. We are importing alot of libraries ;-)

'Gratz on your first contribution! I appreciate it.

it could be an issue with lombok dependancy in pom.xml. Please check if your configuration is as below (change the versions according to your use case)
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
    <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    <version>1.18.24</version> 
    <scope>provided</scope> 
</dependency>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>11</source> 
                <target>11</target>
                <annotationProcessorPaths>
                    <path>
                        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        <version>${lombok.version}</version> 
                    </path>
                </annotationProcessorPaths>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>


I forgot to mention that I also tried provided in the Lombok dependency. Otherwise, the only difference with my POM is that I declared explicit versions for the maven-compiler-plugin and lombok in the annotationProcessorPaths. Also, I set the source and target as 17, as I'm using Java 17.
